# Spring boot failed when trying to build a Rest service

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

Good afternoon I am trying to generate a Rest service with java spring boot, but when trying to execute the jar I get the following error, which is giving me a headache and I don't know what it is specifically:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;)V
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:67)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.getConfigurationSource(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:66)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:58)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:385)
>     at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)  at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:384)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
>     at
>   com.example.consulta.SpringBootSoapApp.main(SpringBootSoapApp.java:12)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>
> java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: findAnnotationCache   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2070)     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.clear(Restarter.java:376)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.cleanupKnownCaches(Restarter.java:361)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.cleanupCaches(Restarter.java:348)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.access$000(Restarter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$1.call(Restarter.java:170)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$1.call(Restarter.java:165)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter$LeakSafeThread.run(Restarter.java:602)

Annex my code

```
package com.example.consulta;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

main.class

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootSoapApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootSoapApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.consulta.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.consulta.entity.Cliente;
import com.example.consulta.service.ClienteService;

@RestController
public class ClienteController {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteService  clienteService;

    @GetMapping("/allCliente")
    public List<Cliente> listarCliente(){
        return clienteService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/cliente/{cedula}")
    public Cliente detalleCliente(@PathVariable int cedula) {
        return clienteService.findById(cedula);
    }


}
```

DAO

```
package com.example.consulta.DAO;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.consulta.entity.Cliente;

public interface ClienteDAO extends CrudRepository<Cliente, Integer>{
}
```

Entity

```
package com.example.consulta.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="Cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    private int cedula;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String tipo_cliente;

    public int getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }
    public void setCedula(int cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }
    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }
    public String getTipo_cliente() {
        return tipo_cliente;
    }
    public void setTipo_cliente(String tipo_cliente) {
        this.tipo_cliente = tipo_cliente;
    }   

}
```

Service

```
package com.example.consulta.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.consulta.entity.Cliente;

public interface ClienteService {

    public List<Cliente> findAll();
    public Cliente findById(int cedula);

}
```

ServiceImpl

```
package com.example.consulta.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.consulta.DAO.ClienteDAO;
import com.example.consulta.entity.Cliente;

@Service

    public class ClienteServiceImpl implements ClienteService{

        @Autowired
        private ClienteDAO clienteDao;


        @Transactional
        public List<Cliente> findAll() {
            return (List<Cliente>) clienteDao.findAll();
        }

        public Cliente findById(int cedula) {
            return clienteDao.findById(cedula).get();
        }


    }
```

pom.xml

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.consulta</groupId>
  <artifactId>ServiceConsultaCliente</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>ServiceConsultaCliente</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
         <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
         <version>12.2.0.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
          <id>codelds</id>
           <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
          </repository>
    </repositories>   
</project>
```

application.properties

```
# Oracle settings

    spring.application.name=prueba-microservicio-cliente
    server.port=8001
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.164.7.203:1521/ORCLPDB1.localdomain
    spring.datasource.username=cesar
    spring.datasource.password=xxxxx123
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

[image]

**UPDATE** After doing what specified by Marcos Barrero I get the following error:
error i get:

pom.xml (final)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.consulta</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceConsultaCliente</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ServiceConsultaCliente</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see your problem is the way you're importing the dependencies, the recommended way to do so is by using the Spring Boot's parent pom and its managed dependencies.

I recommend you to use start.spring.io to generate your next projects, here's a sample with the Spring Boot dependencies that you have, the major diff is the parent pom.

For your project, you need to add the extra dependencies such as `oracle` and any further configuration you have.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.consulta</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceConsultaCliente</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ServiceConsultaCliente</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

UPDATE

Here's your version with `h2` (you have to change it to oracle)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.consulta</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceConsultaCliente</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ServiceConsultaCliente</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- change it to oracle driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: when trying to add the pom to place as an answer I get this error:

C: \ Users \ E10697 \ .m2 \ repository \ org \ springframework \ boot \ spring-boot-starter-parent \ 2.2.4.RELEASE \ spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom: final tag name </span> must match the name of the <input> start tag on line 118 (position: START_TAG seen ... type = "text" name = "query" maxlength = "150" class = "ac_input" > </span>. .. @ 118: 103)

Comment: Can you share the final `pom.xml`?

Comment: Now add what appears to me

Comment: I think you missed the oracle dependency, I just copied your latest `pom.xml`, added the `h2` dependency (so it won't break because of the `datasource` and it just worked.
Can you try to run a `mvn clean package`?

Comment: You cannot make a clean mvn package because of the error it presents with the spring-boot-starter-parent tag, because if I remove that tag it will return to normal

Comment: Can you copy the last pom.xml that worked for you in your answer?

Comment: The same mistake my friend, the one who comments above

Comment: I'm starting to believe that you have a problem with your environment rather than the pom itself.

Comment: What could I do to remove the .m2 repository?

Comment: Navigate to `C:/Users/E10697/.m2` and remove the `repository` folder, as you're on Windows I do believe you need to change some property in the OS to show the hidden folders (.m2)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add spring boot parent pom. With it you shouldn't specify starters versions - parent pom contains all information about needed versions.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use this pom.xml

It was generated by https://start.spring.io/ and I inserted your Oracle dependencies and repositories.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.consulta</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiceConsultaCliente</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ServiceConsultaCliente</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>codelds</id>
        <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: I indicated this error that I do not understand:
Project build error: Non-parseable POM C:\Users\E10697\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\2.2.4.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.4.RELEASE.pom: end tag name </span> must match start tag name <input> from line 118 (position: START_TAG seen ... type="text" name="query" maxlength="150" class="ac_input"></span>... @118:103)

Comment: Are you under a proxy server?

Comment: @CesarJusto Its sound as maven does not download the dependencies. Maybe a proxy server is blocking.

Answer (score 0):

When you face NoSuchMethodException at runtime, it generally means 'classpath hell' - e.g., for simplification, when you've got two version of the same library (one containing the method, but the other - not) and only god knows which version will actually get into your final build if you don't do anything.

To find such dependencies, you shoult run 'mvn dependency:tree' command and search for something related to 'org.springframework.boot.devtools'... => most probably you'll see two versions

Then - you should either use  section of maven POM to strictly set the version, or, as guys suggested above - use spring boot parent (also, a more advanced solution is importing a BOM - which is kind of a set of rules for dependency versions).

Comment: If I am working on eclipse how would you do to execute the dependency mvn command: tree?

Comment: this is a terminal command - it's IDE-independent. Eclipse has a terminal build-in, but you can use the terminal of the OS (powershell is preferred over cmd for windows)